# web2py SQLFORM.factory no_table

Tags: forms, web2py

I would like to know why my variables in web2py SQLFORM.factory have a no_table_[name] instead of the actual table name? Is there anything missing code.

e.g

```
form = SQLFORM.factory(db.event, db.event_permissions, record=record, fields=fields, submit_button='Edit Event Master')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLFORM.factory` works by creating a dummy `DAL` instance along with a dummy `DAL` table. By default, the dummy table name is "no_table", but you can change that via the `table_name` argument.

When you pass entire tables to `SQLFORM.factory`, it simply extracts the fields from those tables, but it does not retain the table names when constructing the HTML widget id's (instead, it just uses the dummy table name to construct the id's). In the book section on [One form for multiple tables](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07#One-form-for-multiple-tables), this is why it says:

> *This only works when the tables don't have field names in common.*

If you have fields with the same names in both tables, they will end up with the same id's.